# Check if a folder exist in server (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am doin a sivleright 4 app.

i would like to check whether a paritcular folder exist **on SERVER** on a button click.

If not create it.

how can this be done?

```
private void btn_checkfolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { // code to check if directory exist on server}
```

Comment: what do mean by on server? are you talking about the IIS where your silverlight app is hosted? also keep this in mind that silverlight is a client based technology is run its code on client machine while server is only the content provider, once the silverlight app is transferred to client, server has no knowledge of what client application is doing(eg its events) until explicitly handled.

Comment: do you mean physical path or URL? Also what is your hosting environment?

Comment: yes i meant on the IIS where sivelright is hosted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight is a client-side technology hence has no knowledge of server side resources. Since your hosting environment is IIS and I assume you want to determine the existence of physical path, think your best shot is to craft a Silverlight enabled web service that will expose a function checking if your desired path exists, then consume it in your Silverlight app.